# How to update JQuery function with another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anybody please help or tell me if it is possible to update an existing jQuery function with another one. I will appreciate any help.

this is the function i want to update

```
   function dataTableFunction1(){
    var table = $('#mytable').dataTable({ "scrollY": "400px","paginate": false });
    table.fnSetColumnVis( 4, false ); 
    table.fnSetColumnVis( 5, false );
    table.fnSetColumnVis( 6, false );    

    }
```

I want to update the  table.fnSetColumnVis part with:

```
   function updateCode(){

    table.fnSetColumnVis( 1, false ); 

    }
```

This is what I tried

```
    dataTableFunction1('option','fnSetColumnVis( 1, false )');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function dataTableFunction1(moreOptions){
    var table = $('#mytable').dataTable({ "scrollY": "400px","paginate": false });

    if(moreOptions == true){
        table.fnSetColumnVis( 4, false ); 
        table.fnSetColumnVis( 5, false );
        table.fnSetColumnVis( 6, false );
    }else{
        table.fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );
    }
}
```

Now, if you want your function to execute with 3 options then:

```
dataTableFunction1(true);
```

And, if you want your function to execute with one option then:

```
dataTableFunction1(false);
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day! appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome :-).  Mark this solution as useful one.